# Creating a loop with BeautifulSoup and putting results into a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code that I am trying to get everything in the GEC column and put it into a list.  My code below can grab the first one which is 'AF' and I can keep adding `find_next('tr')` to grab the next ones but I am having difficulties figuring out how to create a loop in this scenario with beautiful soup.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
from urllib.request import urlopen
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/appendix/appendix-d.html'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

soup.find('tr', {'class', 'appendix-entry ln-a'}).find_next('td').find_next('td').get_text(strip = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print the column GEC:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/appendix/appendix-d.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for gec in soup.table.select('td:nth-child(2)'):
    print(gec.text)
```

Prints:

```
AF
AX
AL
AG
AQ
AN
AO
AV
AY

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks! May I know where ```td:nth-child(2)'``` is from?

Comment: @Xin `td:nth-child(2)` is CSS selector. It means that it will select second `<td>` under the `<table>`/`<tbody>` tag. More on CSS selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

My way of doing that:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
from urllib.request import urlopen
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/appendix/appendix-d.html'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

tr = soup.select('tr.appendix-entry')
for data in tr:
    print(data.select('td')[1].get_text(strip=True))
```